# What kind of data is google chromecast audio collecting?

Tags: streaming, privacy, chromecast

Does anyone know anything about privacy and chromecast audio. I am considering buying one and am wondering, if installing it in my home will give google access to all songs i ever listen to. And the second concern would be to connect that information with some google accounts i might be logged into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does anyone know anything about privacy and chromecast audio?

The Chromecast Privacy policy is available online at [Welcome to the Google Privacy Policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/).

You can modify the [Chromecast privacy settings](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6279421?hl=en-GB):

> **Chromecast privacy settings**
>
> The [Google privacy
>   policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/) describes
>   how we treat personal information when you use Google's products and
>   services, including Chromecast-enabled devices such as Chromecast
>   Audio. This article provides additional information about the privacy
>   settings available to Chromecast users.
>
> **Cast usage data and crash reports**
>
> Google may collect system activity, crash reports and usage data
>   (details about how you use the casting functionality of your Cast
>   device, including the apps and domains you cast).
>
> You can control Google's collection of crash reports and usage data
>   through a device setting, which is enabled by default.
>
> - For Chromecast Audio, you can manage this setting through the device settings menu of the Google Home setup app.
> - For Android TVs, you can manage this setting through the Chromecast settings in the Android TV settings menu.
> - For Chromecast built-in audio devices, you can manage this setting in the device’s utility application settings.
>
> **Performing a factory data reset**
>
> You can perform a factory data reset (FDR) on your Chromecast Audio by
>   using one of the two methods listed below:
>
> Option 1:
>   1.        Open the Google Home app Chromecast cast icon.
>   2.        In the upper-right corner of the home screen, tap Devices  to see your available Chromecast Audio devices.
>   3.        In the top-right corner of the device that you'd like to FDR, tap the device card menu  > Settings.
>   4.        In the top-right corner, tap the More button .
>   5.        Tap Factory reset or Reset.
>   6.        Confirm that you would like to reset your device by tapping Reset.    Option 2:
>
> While the Chromecast is plugged into the TV, hold down the button on
>   the Chromecast for at least 25 seconds or until the solid LED light
>   begins flashing on the Chromecast device and the TV goes blank and
>   begins the reboot sequence.
>
> **Casting from apps and websites**
>
> When you cast content to your device with Chromecast built-in, the
>   application or website that you are using will have its own logging
>   practices and policies with regard to user data. A unique identifier
>   for your devices with Chromecast built-in may be sent to the operator
>   of that app or website for purposes of digital rights management
>   ('DRM'). To learn more, please reference the privacy policies of the
>   apps or websites that you are using.

Comment: does that "You can control Google's collection of crash reports and usage data through a device setting, which is enabled by default." mean, that you can disable the collection of usage data?

Comment: @niklas Yes, try the settings to see how to do it. Also note the last paragraph "When you cast content to your device with Chromecast built-in, the application or website that you are using will have its own logging practices and policies with regard to user data." ... "please reference the privacy policies of the apps or websites that you are using."